# JSX, hide an element using inline ternary operator?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I want to hide a table element when the courses array is empty. I was hoping the code below would work, but it doesn't. Any ideas? The line of code in question is:

`<table className="table" style={courses.length > 0 ? 'show' : 'display:none'}>`

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import CourseListRow from './CourseListRow';

const CourseList = ({courses, onDelete}) => {
  return (
    <table className="table" style={courses.length > 0 ? 'show' : 'display:none'}>
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Author</th>
        <th>Category</th>
        <th>Length</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      {courses.map(course =>
        <CourseListRow key={course.id} course={course} onDelete={onDelete}/>
      )}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};

CourseList.propTypes = {
  courses: PropTypes.array.isRequired
};

export default CourseList;
```

Comment: How would you apply an inline style to a react component *without* the ternary operator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't seem necessary to apply a dynamic class here, but why not just return an empty element (`<span />`) instead of the table itself?

```
const CourseList = ({courses, onDelete}) => {
      if (courses.length === 0) 
          return <span />
      }
      return (
          <table className="table">
              ...
          </table>
      );
};
```

This is a fairly common approach in React, as it allows to actually remove elements from the DOM, as oppose to hiding them with CSS.

Answer (score 1):

`<table className="table" style={courses.length > 0 ? 'display: '' : 'display:none'}>`

This syntax accomplishes what I initially set out to do. That said, lux's answer is a better solution. So I went with that. Thanks lux.

Comment: Definitely still a valid approach; flipping classes via props is done often.

Comment: Removing unnecessary elements from the DOM does seem to be a better solution in this case

Answer (score 1):

```
{count>1?(
      <p>if count is greater than 1 show this tag</p>
     ):
     (<p>if count is less than 1 show this tag</p>)
     }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).